# Width of my custom InfoWindow layout is ignored in Google Maps Android API v2

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

The width I set in my custom InfoWindow layout seems to be ignored (it always match_parent).

Am I missing something?

```
mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoWindowAdapter() {

    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker arg0) {

        View v = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.info_window_layout, null);

        // set my custom data

        return v;

    }
});
```

**info_window_layout.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <!-- some custom stuff -->

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Obviously this is just a problem with RelativeLayouts. LinearLayouts work just fine. So I ended with rewriting my layout into a LinearLayout. Luckily it was quite simple so it wasn't a big problem.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it would actually be wrap_content.

The way info window works is by drawing your View to a bitmap and not putting it inside any other ViewGroup. layout_xxx are used by parent View.

Hardcoding these values on some or all children of your RelativeLayout will probably solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

try to use this in getInfoWindow, getInfoContents return null:

```
<LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/transparent">

        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="vertical">

            <!-- some custom stuff -->

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:background="#8BC34A"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/small_padding"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/very_samll_padding"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/very_samll_padding"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/small_padding">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_address"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_latlong"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/tv_address"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/very_samll_padding"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_lat"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="12dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/small_padding"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/small_padding"
            android:background="@color/white" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_long"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Just chnage the width dp according to your requiremnt